# set value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this list of tuples where I can find in first position one index and in second position the value corresponding.

here an example :

```
list_val = [ [(0, 0.9), (451, 0.5)] , [(10, 0.5), (52, 0.2)] ]
an_other_list = [10, 1000, 1002, 1003, ...] # the real index i want
```

in a pandas data frame, I want to set values like this:

```
index = []
for i in list_val:
    index.append(an_other_list[list_val.index(i)])

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in list_val:
    for j in i:

        df.set_value( an_other_list[j[0]], an_other_list[list_val.index(i)], j[1])
```

but this is too slow and I know it's not optimized.

How can I improve this ?

EDIT:

here an output example where all the value are not set yet  :

[image]

I ran this example on a simple dataframe without setting the index as the list "index".

Sorry if it's not enough clear

Comment: what is `an_other_list` and what is your expected output?

Comment: what is `an_other_list`? Did you take a look at any pandas tutorial?

Comment: your `index` creation doesn't look good. `list_val` is not a `list` of `tuple`s. It is a `list` of a `list` of `tuple`s. That might be one reason why your code is not working.

Comment: @HaleemurAli in fact, the index in list_val are not the real index,  I have to use my "an_other_list" to find the real index (corresponding to an id_product). As an output, I want an dataFrame with all the value (i.E 0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2) in the right row and columns.

Comment: @Scotty1- yeah my bad, I did a mistake by re writing this line.  I edited my question

Comment: @agreüs, Can you show us expected output given these inputs?

Comment: @jpp I edited my question, sorry if it's not clear enough

Comment: For me it is hard to figure out what you want. Perhaps some pseudo-code can help to clarify the question.